# "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape" . (File management bug)

Tags: python, directory, file-management

So I'm making a program in Python that goes through all of your files in the download folder but when I run it, it says

(SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape).

I use a variable to store the directory and put it in a for loop with the OS library. please help me. (Windows 11, python 3.9.)

I know many people have asked this question and I have gone through all of the answers but none of them works for me, I think the problem I have, sounds similar to others but it actually is very different, so please don't mark this as duplicate. please help :)

Code:

```
#im trying to make a program that goes through all the files in my downloads folder

import os
from time import sleep


source_dir = "C:\Users\(replace with you'r name to test)\example\Downloads"

with os.scandir(source_dir) as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.name)
        sleep(0.35)
```

I have tried to change the \ with / and with // and with \, but none of the different types work. i have also tried removing the " and also replacing them with ', it didnt work. please help

Comment: your code is running fine there is nothing wrong in it. I have just changed '\' with '/'

Comment: Ye, maybe for you but when i did that there is a new error that says.   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Users/Axelr/example/Downloads'

Comment: I have now fixed the code by deleting the "example directory", thanks everyone for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### And if you want to remove desktop.ini from printing just write this code

```
import os
from time import sleep


source_dir = "C:/Users/DAKSH/Downloads"

for file in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if not (file.endswith('.ini')):
        print(file)
```

Comment: I have now fixed the code by deleting the "example directory", thanks everyone for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#You can also use this to scan your directory and get all filename in it

import os



source_dir = "C:/Users/(replace with you'r name to test)/example/Downloads"

for file in os.listdir(source_dir):
    print(file)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it works but at the start, it says "desktop.ini", do you know how to remove that?

Comment: And also, do you know a way to make my code work?, without changing the os.scandir

Comment: I have now fixed the code by deleting the "example directory", thanks everyone for helping me :)